# Using custom MigrationOperation in CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I would like to create my own migration operations for the CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator, so I created my own migration operation derived from MigrationOperation.

```
public class CustomMigrationOperation : MigrationOperation
{
    public CustomMigrationOperation() : base(null)
    {
        IsDestructiveChange = false;
    }

    public override bool IsDestructiveChange { get; }

    public override MigrationOperation Inverse => null;
}
```

And a customized CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator.

```
public class CustomCSharpMigrationCodeGenerator : CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator
{
    public override ScaffoldedMigration Generate(string migrationId, IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations, string sourceModel, string targetModel,
        string @namespace, string className)
    {
        var extendedOperations = operations.ToList();
        extendedOperations.Add(new CustomMigrationOperation());

        return base.Generate(migrationId, extendedOperations, sourceModel, targetModel, @namespace, className);
    }

    protected virtual void Generate(CustomMigrationOperation operation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

When I run the Add-Migration script in the Package Manager Console I got the following exception:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator.Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.AddColumnOperation, System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.IndentedTextWriter)' has some invalid arguments
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator , Object , IndentedTextWriter )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass35.<Generate>b__27(Object o)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable`1 operations, String namespace, String className)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator.Generate(String migrationId, IEnumerable`1 operations, String sourceModel, String targetModel, String namespace, String className)
   at Custom.Model.CustomCSharpMigrationCodeGenerator`1.Generate(String migrationId, IEnumerable`1 operations, String sourceModel, String targetModel, String namespace, String className) in 
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.Scaffold(String migrationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder scaffolder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator.Generate(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.AddColumnOperation, System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.IndentedTextWriter)' has some invalid arguments
```

After doing some research in the EntityFramework 6 code on Github I found the line that should be responsible for calling the Generate functions of the generator:

```
.Each<dynamic>(o => Generate(o, writer));
```

[CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Migrations/Design/CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator.cs)

I do not understand why C# is not calling the appropiate Generate function.

A workaround is to derive from AddColumnOperation and override the Generate(AddColumnOperation operation, ...) and handle the CustomMigrationOperation specially there. But that's more a hack than a useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is the DLR cannot determine the method.

As an example proof of concept, here's a simplified variation console app displaying the exact same behavior.

```
using MicrosoftGenerator;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AddMigrationRunner {
    class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var generator = (Generator) new Something.Deep.Somewhere.MyCustomGenerator(); // reverse casted simply to dictate the "angle" from which we are coming.

            // PMC:> Add-Migration MyMigrationName
            generator.AddMigration("MyMigrationName"); 
        }
    }
}
namespace MicrosoftGenerator {
    // meant to be a rough "clone" of: https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Migrations/Design/CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator.cs
    public class Generator {
        private List<MigrationOperation> operations = new List<MigrationOperation>() { };

        public Generator() {
            operations.Add(new AddColumnOperation());
        }
        public void AddMigration(string name) {
            Generate(name, operations);
        }
        public virtual void Generate(string migrationId, IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations) {
            Console.WriteLine("Up() method generating..");
            operations.Each<dynamic>(o => Generate(o));
        }


        protected void Generate(AddColumnOperation op) {
            Console.WriteLine("<AddColumnOperation> execute.");
        }
    }

    public class AddColumnOperation : MigrationOperation {}
    public class MigrationOperation {}


 //https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/Common/IEnumerableExtensions.cs
    public static class MicrosoftUtilities {
        public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ts, Action<T> action) {
            foreach (var t in ts) {
                action(t);
            }
        }

    }
}

namespace Something.Deep.Somewhere {
    public class MyCustomGenerator : Generator {
        public MyCustomGenerator() : base() {

        }
        public override void Generate(string migrationId, IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations) {
            var extendedOperations = operations.ToList();
            extendedOperations.Add(new MyCustomOperation());

            base.Generate(migrationId, extendedOperations);
        }

        protected void Generate(MyCustomOperation op) {
            Console.WriteLine("<MyCustomOperation> execute.");
        }
    }
    public class MyCustomOperation : MigrationOperation {

    }
}
```

So by splitting up the custom .Each action executor, into a foreach, we can see that it does work fine if coded decently.

```
            //operations.Each<dynamic>(o => Generate(o));
            foreach(var op in operations) {
                Type op_type = op.GetType();
                var actionT = typeof (Action<>).MakeGenericType(op_type);
                var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("Generate", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { op_type }, null);
                methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[]{ op });
            }
```

I'm out of my depth at this point, to explain why it is that a delegate action with a valid object and instance cannot resolve itself. 
I suppose this is a good example of why you should not use `dynamic` in a lazy fashion. *Cough* @microsoft.

I don't see any way to resolve this without modifying the EntityFramework source code.
The use of `dynamic` would be ok, if they weren't also using a runtime bound Extension method to execute the method as a hard `<type>` parameterized action; since if it was kept as `dynamic` it would remain runtime bound.
As proven (it works!) if you modify their root `Generate` method like so (as per sample above):

```
        public virtual void Generate(string migrationId, IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations) {
            Console.WriteLine("Up() method generating..");
            operations.Each<dynamic>(o => ((dynamic)this).Generate(o));
        }
```

Notice the `((dynamic)this)` cast prefix.
P.s. I gathered that determination from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5299867/4754981).

So 3 things:

1. Thank you for posting this, is exactly what I need also
2. Sorry I don't have a solution
3. and hopefully with this Intel typed out here explicitly, someone with a great mind can show us a way to bypass this problem without opening a ticket on Microsoft's account.

So if you want to keep your code clean like we both do, the only solution I can think of is to NOT call `base.Generate()`, and instead implement a copy/paste of their source code; such that you may override their extension method `.Each` call to `delegate`. Which is obviously problematic for nuget updates and future dev's who know-not what they do.

One must get dirty to get clean. I don't like that one bit.